# How to install Matplotlib's basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

It is unclear to me how to install Matplotlib's [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) on Windows. Maybe the question is straightforward, I need some help.

I followed [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html). As far as I understand, first, `GEOS` and `PROJ4` should be installed, and lastly `matplotlib-1.4.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` should be executed.

I get stuck with GEOS. I downloaded source code of geos-3.5.0, "untarred" it, then I go to a Command Prompt, change directory to geos-3.5.0 and run this:

```
export d://test
```

but it does not work.

Comment: @Leb: I got errors. That's why I got stuck.

Comment: You didn't list any, you said you're stuck. Have you tried using `whl` package?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this [download](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap) for basemap on Windows.

It worked for me:

```
pip install basemap-1.0.8-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Assuming you're in right directory of course.

Comment: You're welcome. It also got [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) if you need it. Very useful.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but could you please elaborate on what you mean by "Assuming you're in right directory"? When I try to run the command, I get the error: `ERROR: basemap‑1.2.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

Comment: @Qwethm You need to run your command in the same folder as the basemap-1.0.8-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl file (i.e in your downloads folder).

Answer (score 3):

This is the alternate solution that might useful for anaconda users

For only Anaconda Users, they can get it to install on the local machine through the following command:

```
conda install basemap
```

This will auto-install all required dependency packages.

Here also, Assuming that User are at the right directory to install any module.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as I pip installed and then conda installed and then had to do a clean install as dependencies were a mess.

At that time I solved my problem by using Google Colab and installing the following:

```
!apt-get install -q libgeos-3.5.0
!apt-get install -q libgeos-dev
!pip install -q https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
!pip install -q pyproj==1.9.6
```

I would also recommend reading [Importing-of-Basemap-in-Google-Colab](https://community.insaid.co/hc/en-us/community/posts/360048243414-Installing-Importing-of-Basemap-in-Google-Colab) as it helped with Colab installation.

Answer (score 0):

while importing like (from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap) I was getting error.

For me This Worked Like charm:

> pip install basemap

Comment: Worked for me when everything else didn't ! I'm not found of pip command but i couldn't manage to install basemap with conda. Thank you !