# Getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, data-analysis

**I've tried to install Basemap package with both Pycharm & Jupiter notebook**

```
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
   import geopy       
   !pip install Basemap
```

[Providing ss of my Jupiter notebook window below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtIxk.png)

*Please help me with this.*

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020202/how-to-install-matplotlibs-basemap

Comment: Hi Madhumati. A suggestion to get more answers is to copy and paste the jupyter notebook output into your question rather than linking to a screenshot.

Comment: @alex_danielssen Thanks for your suggestion definitely do this next time.

Comment: @Jonas No it's not working tried it.

Answer (score 0):

you should install new modules at location where your program notebook/python/paycharm/ install.

Generally, it should be at below path but you need to change location as per machine:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

Then, you can Type `cmd` on address bar and then press `Enter`

Once command prompt open in your machine then you need to mention you `pip` command

```
pip install youmodualname
```

Or, For Anaconda Environment and basemap module

```
conda install basemap
```

once you run above command on command prompt you will get successfully install same on your machine.

**Note:** You must have latest Anaconda-python version to meet requirement of modules while installing it